# Is it possible to assign a field value as a key for a Map query

Tags: apex, soql, query, map, sobject

I am wondering if it's possible to create something similar to this:

```
Map<sObject.field, sObject> mapOfsObject = new Map<sObject.field, sObject> ([
  SELECT field
  FROM sObject
]);
```

I know this is possible with the Id of the sObject. But I cannot make it work for a different field. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't automatically assign an SObject map by any value other than Id. For any other field, you have to use a standard loop:

```
for(SObject record: [...]) {
    mapOfSObject.put(record.Field__c, record);
}
```

Comment: I usually do that `for loop` but was hoping that there could be a way to avoid using it. Thank you.

Comment: It would be nice if this were possible without the for loop to manually build the map...but I'd pray for the soul of the poor sap who got stuck with trying to implement that feature.

Comment: @DerekF I think it'd be simple, actually... just provide an extra map parameter: `new Map<String, SObject>(Account.Name, [select ...])`. In fact, all they'd have to do is generalize the code that's already there.